# safari and IE11 won't play html5 video

Tags: html, internet-explorer, safari, html5-video

Why wont this simple piece of code work on safari and IE ?

Do i need to have a flash fallback for IE11, im not getting any errors in the console at all, i just get the player shell and nothing will play

```
 <video id="video" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px #000 solid;" autoplay>
                        <source src="videos/c1rcardiffrmackeyrunit1.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                        <source src="videos/c1rcardiffrmackeyrunit1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="videos/c1rcardiffrmackeyrunit1.webm" type="video/webm">
                </video>
```

Comment: f12>emulation tab, which emulation mode is your web site mapped to?

Comment: IE is mapped to Edge, dont think safari has that option does it?

Comment: are you using any javascript to start/stop the video? I just ran into an issue where trying to `play()` a video was not working in Safari and IE but fine in Chrome and FF. Removing the javascript call to `play()` solved my issue.